# LLamar un servicio api rest desde base de datos Oracle

Tags: api, oracle, rest

Es posible que al registrarse en una tabla de Oracle un registro con una columna valor 0 se pueda llamar un endpoint de api para intentar actualizar dicho valor?

No he encontrado una solución para implementar ello, lo único que se me ocurre es tener un servicio que este consultando constantemente a la base de datos, pero no me parece muy eficiente

Comment: De poder, se puede, acabo de hacer una búsqueda en internet y de los enlaces que encontré, aquí algunos: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_HTTP.html#GUID-A85D2D1F-90FC-45F1-967F-34368A23C9BB + https://www.oratable.com/utl_http/ Por cierto, revisa también: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour + https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask + https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Bienvenido a SOes. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.